# flutter - how to get effects like css flex display none

Tags: flexbox, flutter

in html css, whether `#gone` have `display: none;` browser will have different display

```
    .main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
    }
    #gone {
        visibility: hidden;
        /* display: none; */
    }
    <div class="main">
        <div>text 1</div>
        <div id="gone">text 1</div>
        <div>text 1</div>
        <div>text 1</div>
    </div>
```

[With display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zey8O.png)

[Without display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvr70.png)

In flutter, using `Visibility with visible: false` will get effect like [Without display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvr70.png)

```
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("test1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: false,
          child: Text("test1",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
        ),
        Text("test1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
        Text("test1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

How to get effects like [With display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zey8O.png)  in flutter?
English is poor :-(

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to remove the `mainAxisAlignment` property from your `Row` and handle the spacing yourself:

```
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      "test1",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Visibility(
      visible: false,
      child: Flexible(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "test1",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      "test1",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Text(
      "test1",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just visually hiding the widget, you can show an empty container with size of 0 like this:

```
bool hide = true;
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("test1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
        hide==true?Container():Visibility(
          visible: false,
          child: Text("test1",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
        ),
        Text("test1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
        Text("test1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

In this example, if the variable "hide" is true, it will show an empty container, and when the variable "hide" is false, it will show your invisible text.

Comment: Test failed, the code same as [Without display: none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvr70.png)

I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zey8O.png)